# How to get `self` instance in `mock.Mock().call_args`?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I observe an inconsistent behavior when patching a dummy class:

```py
class A:

  def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

If I patch manually the function:

```py
call_args_list = []
def mock_fn(*args, **kwargs):
  call_args_list.append(mock.call(*args, **kwargs))

with mock.patch.object(A, 'f', mock_fn):
  A().f(1, 2)

print(call_args_list)  # [call(<__main__.A object at 0x7f0da0c08b50>, 1, 2)]
```

As expected `mock_fn` is called with the `self` argument (`mock_fn(self, 1, 2)`).

However, if I'm using a `mock.Mock` object, somehow the `self` argument is removed from the call:

```py
mock_obj = mock.Mock()

with mock.patch.object(A, 'f', mock_obj):
  A().f(1, 2)

print(mock_obj.call_args_list)  # [call(1, 2)]
```

This feel inconsistent. `mock_obj` is called as `mock_obj(self, 1, 2)`, yet `mock_obj.call_args == call(1, 2)`. It removes the `self` argument from `call_args`. How can I access the bounded-method instance ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```py
with mock.patch.object(A, 'f', autospec=True) as mock_obj:
    A().f(1, 2)

print(mock_obj.call_args_list)  # [call(<__main__.A object at 0x7fb2908fc880>, 1, 2)]
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods):

> If you pass `autospec=True` [...] the mocked function will be turned into a bound method if it is fetched from an instance. It will have `self` passed in as the first argument [...]

Answer (score 1):

From the Python console, `help(mock.MethodType)`:

> Create a bound instance method object.

```
from unittest import mock

class A:

  def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass


mock_obj = mock.Mock()
a = A()
with mock.patch.object(A, 'f', mock_obj):
    a.f(1, 2)
    print(mock_obj.call_args)

# fixed self in call_args by patching
# with a bound instance method mock
mock_obj = mock.Mock()
with mock.patch.object(A, 'f', mock.MethodType(mock_obj, a)):
    a.f(1, 2)
    print(mock_obj.call_args)
```

Output:

```
call(1, 2)
call(<__main__.A object at 0x7ff8223e1dc0>, 1, 2)
```

Comment: I don't understand the answer. I already know how to extract `self` with `def mock_fn`, as shown in my example. However, I would like to do it using `mock.Mock().call_args`

Comment: @Conchylicultor : Sorry, the example was confusing in making you think mock_fn was needed. I hope my intent is clear now.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, this solution assume that (1) the bounded object is already created when `mock.patch` is called. (2) That only a single instance of `A` will ever be created. Calling `b = A() ; b.f()` will call `a.f` instead of `b.f`. None of those assumptions hold for my use-case