# Check the value of Path-object when mocking unlink()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-3.8

My productive code takes a `pathlib.Path` instance and creates a second one with modified suffix out of it and delete that second file if it exists.

```
def productive_code(fp):
    # "foo" + ".wrong" + ".csv" = "foo.wrong.csv"
    fp.with_suffix('.wrong{}'.format(fp.suffix))
    
    fp_wrong.unlink(missing_ok=True)  # >= Python3.8
```

In the unittest I patch the `pathlib.Path.unlink()` and I can check if and with which parameters it was called.

But how can I check the "value" of the path object itself? I want to test if the "second" file name was correct created.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import pathlib

    class TestMy(unittest.TestCase):
        @mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink')
        def test_unlink(self, mock_unlink):
            productive_code(pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
            mock_unlink.assert_called_once_with(missing_ok=True)
            # test "foo.wrong.csv" !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to define a `side_effect` and to mock the `Path` object itself (using `wraps`) but to no avail.

But I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70019238/11384184) and it works fine !
You can use `autospec=True` to turn

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import pathlib


def productive_code(fp):
    # "foo" + ".wrong" + ".csv" = "foo.wrong.csv"
    fp_wrong = fp.with_suffix('.wrong').with_suffix(fp.suffix)

    fp_wrong.unlink(missing_ok=True)  # >= Python3.8


class TestMy(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink', autospec=True)
    #                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    def test_unlink(self, mock_unlink):
        productive_code(pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
        mock_unlink.assert_called_once_with(pathlib.Path("foo.wrong.csv"), missing_ok=True)
```

This info was not in the [mock library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) but from the ["getting started" page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mock-for-method-calls-on-an-object) which is linked nowhere but in the "Next section" buttons. I'm aghast I'm discovering it just now !

Back on the subject, now that you can check which path gets `unlink`ed, you will notice that your `productive_code` implementation is wrong : you assumed that calling `with_suffix` twice would concatenate both, but that's not the case, per [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) :

> Return a new path with the suffix changed.

In essence :

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("a.txt").with_suffix(".mp3")
PosixPath('a.mp3')
>>> Path("a.txt").with_suffix(".mp3").with_suffix(".html")
PosixPath('a.html')
>>> Path("a.txt.mp3.html").with_suffix(".zip")
PosixPath('a.txt.mp3.zip')
```

Another approach to the testing problem would be [this code review's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237063/243008) :

> Mocking system calls, especially those with side effects (mkdir()), is difficult and error prone.
> [...]
> If you really need to mock the filesystem part, I would suggest using an existing library such as pyfakefs, although I have never had such a need.

If your testcode goes very wrong, you could damage your system (unlinking files that should not).

PS: nice minimal reproducible example :)